# SQLAlchemy: Relationship inference?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

In the much-needed "[10 common stumbling blocks for SQLAlchemy newbies](http://alextechrants.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/10-common-stumbling-blocks-for.html)", clause 9 states: (emphasis mine)

> **9. Wanting to commit the session to get the ID of an object so it can be used to insert related objects**
>
> Most nontrivial SQLAlchemy applications need to work with
>   relationships. Imagine a situation like this: You need to create a
>   Company and add an Employee to it. You already have a relationship
>   called employees in the Company class. So how would you accomplish
>   this task? The typical answer goes along the lines of:
>
> 1. Create the Company instance
> 2. Add the Company instance to the session
> 3. Flush the session
> 4. Create the Employee instance with company_id from the previously flushed Company instance
> 5. Add the Employee instance to the session
> 6. Commit the session
>
> This is just about how you'd do it without SQLAlchemy. But with
>   SQLAlchemy this can be done much easier:
>
> 1. Create the Company instance
> 2. Create the Employee instance
> 3. **Add the Company instance to the session**
> 4. Commit the session
>
> When the session is flushed, the Company row is first inserted to the
>   database. **Then, by virtue of relationship cascade, the Employee**
>   **instance is discovered and also inserted into the database.** The RDBMS
>   can't tell the difference, but for the developer, the latter approach
>   is much nicer.

How is SQLAlchemy inferring the relationship? what if I don't want it to associate two instances whose classes are stated to have a relationship? And when should I commit if I'm doing insertions/updates inside a loop?

Comment: SQLAlchemy does not infer relationships; you have to declare them in your model using [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Oh, that I know. It may have been wishful thinking, but the author of said article doesn't say anything about associating the `Company` with `Employee` in his steps, so I thought maybe it's done somehow automatically for the instances. Oh well, explicit is always better than implicit!